# iothub.Device is not a constructor at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

With NodeJS I am using the basic sample documentation from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-getstarted

However I get this error:

> iothub.Device is not a constructor at Object.
>   (/Users/luis.valencia/Projects/IoTSamples/NodeJSIoTHelloWorld
>   /CreateDeviceIdentity.js:7:14) at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10) at Module.load
>   (module.js:458:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3) at Module.runMain
>   (module.js:575:10) at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7) at startup
>   (bootstrap_node.js:144:9) at bootstrap_node.js:467:3

My code is as follows:

```
'use strict';
var iothub = require('azure-iothub');
var connectionString = 'HostName=xyz.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=xyz=';
var registry = iothub.Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
var deviceId = "helloworlddevice";

var device = new iothub.Device(null);
device.deviceId = deviceId;

registry.create(device, function(err, deviceInfo, res) {
  if (err)
    registry.get(device.deviceId, printDeviceInfo); 

  if (deviceInfo)
    printDeviceInfo(err, deviceInfo, res) 
});

function printDeviceInfo(err, deviceInfo, res) {
  if (deviceInfo)
    console.log('Generated device key: ' + deviceInfo.authentication.SymmetricKey.primaryKey);
}
```

Comment: shame on the -1, and no comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug on the npm package, after reporting it to MS on github, it was fixed, released overnight, so I just installed the package again and the problem was solved.